# simplify summation with binomial coefficients

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

Is there a way to simplify this summation?:

> $$\sum ^n _{k=0}  \left(n-k\right)!\binom{n}{k}^2$$

Comment: Have you tried expanding?

Comment: Have you tried https://oeis.org/ ?

Comment: It can be simplified to $n!\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}\binom{n}{k}$.  I don't know if it can be evaluated.

Comment: yes, I got that too in the form of $n!\sum ^n _{k=0} \frac{\binom{n}{k}}{k!}$

Comment: @Prakhar Nagpal Note correction.

Comment: @herbsteinberg sorry my bad, forgot about the $n!$

Comment: thank u @PrakharNagpal  :) is there a way to make it even simpler? to a point where i don't need to use k at all

Comment: I'm trying to figure that out

Answer (score 1):

Alright, some of the comments have pointed out that it seems pretty difficult to find a definite formula but we can simplify it down to something much nicer to handle. We have, $$\sum ^n _{k=0}  \left(n-k\right)!\binom{n}{k}^2$$ Now, multiplying and dividing $k!$ and $n!$we get, $$n! \sum^n _{k=0} \frac{1}{k!} \frac{\left(n-k\right)! \cdot k!}{n!} \cdot\binom{n}{k}^2 $$ This is equivalent to $$n! \sum^n _{k=0} \frac{\binom{n}{k}^2}{\binom{n}{k}k!}$$ Which is $$n! \sum^n _{k=0} \frac{\binom n k}{k!}$$

Answer (score 0):

The simplest form seems to be $n! L_n(-1)$, where $L_n(x)$ is a Laguerre polynomial.